# How to test for the existance of a bootstrap vue component in unit tests with jest?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

So I have some code that has a `b-form-input` component  and I am testing whether that component renders. I am using `wrapper.find({name: "b-form-input"}).exists()` to determine whether that bootstrap vue component exists. However this function continually returns false when I know that the component is rendering. Could I have some help on how to do this correctly?

Comment: What does `wrapper.html()` give you? You could `import { BInputGroup } from 'bootstrap-vue'` and use `wrapper.find(BInputGroup)`. Looking at the source, the component's name is "BInputGroup", so you may need to use `wrapper.find({name: "BInputGroup"})`

Comment: Yeah the second one worked, I also made a typo which I fixed saying I was looking for b-input-group when I was looking for b-form-input. The first method gave an error saying: `[vue-test-utils]: wrapper.find() must be passed a valid CSS selector, Vue constructor, or valid find option object`. Will you write up an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the `bootstrap-vue` source code, it looks like the name of the element is `BFormInput` and not `b-form-input` (it was registered using kebab-case):

> https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/2fb5ce823a577fcc2414d78bd43ed9e5351cb1c0/src/components/form-input/form-input.js#L33
>
> ```js
> ...
> export const BFormInput = /*#__PURE__*/ Vue.extend({
>   name: 'BFormInput',
>   ...
> ```

You have two options to locate the component; using the name, or the component constructor. For example:

```js
import BootstrapVue, { BFormInput } from 'bootstrap-vue';
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(BootstrapVue);

describe('HelloWorld.vue', () => {
  it('BFormInput exists', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(HelloWorld, { localVue })
    expect(wrapper.find({ name: 'BFormInput' }).exists()).toBe(true);
    expect(wrapper.find(BFormInput).exists()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is not working with vue3. It gives error for Vue.extends.

Comment: This answer was written over 4 years ago. The error you're seeing is probably related to BootstrapVue's Vue 3 support: https://bootstrap-vue.org/vue3. That said, if you're building a new app with Vue 3 you should should be using Vitest and Testing Library instead of Jest and Vue Test Utils directly.