# How to trigger event with Vue Test Utils on a BootstrapVue element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, bootstrap-vue, vue-test-utils

This issue gives me a hard time and I can't understand how to make **Vue Test Utils** and **BootstrapVue** play nice together.

A minimal example would look like this:

**`MyComponent.vue`**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-button variant="primary" @click="play">PLAY</b-button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  methods: {
    play() {
      console.log("Let's play!");
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In the `main.js` we use **BootstrapVue**: `Vue.use(BootstrapVue)`.

This is how I'm trying to test that the `click` event has been triggered:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import Vue from 'vue';
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import BootstrapVue, { BButton } from 'bootstrap-vue';
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent.vue';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(BootstrapVue);

describe('MyComponent.vue', () => {
  it('should call the method play when button is clicked', () => {
    const playSpy = sinon.spy();
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
      localVue,
      methods: {
        play: playSpy,
      },
    });
    wrapper.find(BButton).trigger('click');
    expect(playSpy.called).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

This gives me:

> ```
>   AssertionError: expected false to equal true
>   + expected - actual
>
>   -false
>   +true
> ```

I checked [How to test for the existance of a bootstrap vue component in unit tests with jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56998626/how-to-test-for-the-existance-of-a-bootstrap-vue-component-in-unit-tests-with-je), but it doesn't apply to `BButton`.

When running the test I also don't see any output on the command line, where I would expect this line to be executed:

```
console.log("Let's play!");
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: To get your console.log running, you could try this:

wrapper.vm.play()

Comment: @lucas Thanks, but my goal is not to get the `console.log` running by explicitly calling the method. I want to test that triggering the `click` event will call the method.

Comment: got it. But does it work? Another option is trying to change this to wrapper.find('b-button').trigger('click') instead

Comment: @lucas No, `wrapper.find('b-button')` won't work. Neither `wrapper.find('button')` will. You have to pass the component name to the `find` method of `wrapper` when using **BoostrapVue**. I don't how to proceed further in order to trigger an event.

Comment: I'm not familiar with BootstrapVue, but I have an idea that might help you. Check how they test the buttons on their repository. It hopefully might give you some insight.
https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/src/components/button/button.spec.js

Comment: @lucas Besten Dank! Why I didn't look at the source earlier. The issue is with `shallowMount`, which doesn't go recursively to render the child components. As I mentioned before, **BootstrapVue** provides Vue components. `BButton` is a component, which is called as `<b-button>` inside my component. Therefore I have to use `mount` for test cases like this one.

Comment: Cool! Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason why the event `click` couldn't be triggered is the way how `shallowMount` works in contrast to `mount`.

As we know, Vue Test Utils provide two methods to mount a component, i.e. render the template and generate a DOM tree:

- mount
- shallowMount

The first method `mount` generates a complete DOM tree and traverses through all child components. Most of the time this is not necessary, so the method `shallowMount` is preferred - it stubs the child components just one level below the parent component.

In my case this was also the root of the problem. **BootstrapVue** provides components, like `BButton`, which can be used in your own Vue templates. That means that in the following template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-button variant="primary" @click="play">PLAY</b-button>
  </div>
</template>
```

the **b-button** is a child component, which is stubbed when using `shallowMount` in the unit tests for our component. That's the reason why we can't find an element button:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent);
wrapper.find('button'); // won't work
```

We can find the child component like this:

```
wrapper.find(BButton); // BButton has to be imported from bootstrap-vue
```

but if we try to output the rendered element:

```
console.log(wrapper.find(BButton).element);
```

we'll get:

```
HTMLUnknownElement {}
```

The `BButton` as a child component hasn't been fully rendered and there is no `button` element in the DOM tree. But when we use `mount` we have this behaviour:

```
const wrapper = mount(MyComponent);
console.log(wrapper.find(BButton).element);
```

we'll get:

```
HTMLButtonElement { _prevClass: 'btn btn-primary' }
```

We see that `mount` has rendered the child component. When we use `mount` we can directly access the `button` element:

```
wrapper.find('button');
```

Now that we have the `button` we can trigger an event like `click` on it.

I hope this helps other beginners too. The examples are very simplified, don't forget to create `localVue` using `createLocalVue` and pass it to the `mount` method as illustrated in the question.

When using **BootstrapVue** think very carefully which mounting method you need.

Comment: And also applicable to any other component library (or even your own child components), not just BootstrapVue

Comment: @TroyMorehouse Yes, you're absolutely right. Here we set an example on BootstrapVue, which I believe is a popular library.

Answer (score 4):

While still performing a `shallowMount` you should be able to do this:

`wrapper.find(BButton).vm.$listeners.click();`